# Hibernate criteria - join multiple tables and form a user object

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

I am trying to join multiple tables and to map the table columns to list of user objects.

Below is the SQL query and I am trying to convert to ORM using Hibernate Criteria:

```
SELECT table1.domainname, table2.policyname,table3.filterpath,table4.userdirectoryname
FROM table1, table2,table3, table4 
WHERE table3.domainoid = table1.domainoid
AND table3.policyoid = table2.policyoid
AND table3.userdirectoryoid = table4.userdirectoryoid  
AND table1.domainname = 'admin'
```

From the above query, we will get a list of user objects and trying to map the results to the user object. Below is the POJO class of the user object to form.

```
public class DomainDetails {
    String domainName, policyName, filterPath, userDirName;

    public DomainDetails(String domainName, String policyName, String filterPath, String userDirName) {
        super();
        this.domainName = domainName;
        this.policyName = policyName;
        this.filterPath = filterPath;
        this.userDirName = userDirName;
    }

    // getters and setters...
}
```

How to join the multiple tables and the mapping of the respective columns to the user object?

appreciate the help..thanks

Comment: Please, add the entities.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **mapping annotation** ..
[Mapping entity associations/relationships](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-association)